# Using if function in laravel

Tags: laravel, if-statement

I am having some trouble doing an if statement since most of the tutorial videos and other forums, I saw people only using variable, example $value, but I want to use if statement on the input name itself. Is that possible, if so could you help me out? Thanks a lot. Sorry if you are feeling confused of what I want maybe, if you see the code, you might understand, I don't really quite know how to say it in words.

test.blade.php

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2"><b>Test:</b></label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="No"> No<br>
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="Pending"> Pending<br> 
      </div>

@if(<input type="radio" name = "test" value="Yes"> || <input type="radio" name = "test" value="Pending">)
//show some other kind of input types such as :
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2"><b>Training Schedule:</b></label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="training_schedule" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="training_schedule" value="No"> No<br>
      </div>
@else
//make the other inputs value become NIL instead of showing
Something like:
    name = "training_schedule" value = "NIL"
    @endif
```

Comment: You can't do like that. Just use javascipt to do that.

Comment: Do you the name of what it called? Or you mean the normal if else statement in javascript?

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: Looking at it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example using the javascript.

```js
var test_input = $('input[name=test]');
var test_val = '';

var if_yes = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-2"><b>Training Schedule:</b></label><div class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="training_schedule" value="Yes"> Yes<br><input type="radio" name="training_schedule" value="No"> No<br></div></div>';
var if_no = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-2"><b>Training Schedule:</b></label><div class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="training_schedule" value="NIL"> NIL</div></div>';


$(test_input).on('change', function () {
  test_val = $(this).val();
  if (test_val == 'Yes' || test_val == 'Pending') {
    //clear the div
    $('div#append_to_this').html('');
    
    // put your html code here
    $('div#append_to_this').append(if_yes);
  } else {
    //clear the div
    $('div#append_to_this').html('');
    
    // put your html code here
    $('div#append_to_this').append(if_no);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-2"><b>Test:</b></label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
               <input type="radio" name="test" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
               <input type="radio" name="test" value="No"> No<br>
               <input type="radio" name="test" value="Pending"> Pending<br> 
          </div>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div id="append_to_this"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also do not know how to create the html code where I would give the radio button value a fixed value. For example, name = "training_schedule" value = "NIL" under the else part, could you show me how

Comment: Just copy your form to that append. updated @blastme

Comment: is this suppose to be the location for the js? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Or it is needed for the js to work. And also do I put it together with the form inside or in another folder? Sorry it my first time using js together with laravel

Comment: You can just write the JS directly in app.js, make sure you're running the npm run watch-poll to compile your assets. For little bits of JS like this there's no need to create new files.

Comment: No, it can be different location. You must include jQuery no matter where the location. @blastme